# Including form data in another page

Tags: php, html, forms

When I post my form data:

```
<form action="layouts.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="bgcolor">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" align="middle">
</form>
```

to a php page, "layouts.php", it returns the string, as expected.:

```
$bgcolor = $_POST['bgcolor'];
echo $bgcolor; //returns "red"
echo gettype($bgcolor); // returns "string"
```

But when I include "layouts.php" in another page it returns NULL.

```
<?php
  include("php/layouts.php");
  echo $bgcolor; //
  echo gettype($bgcolor); //returns "NULL"
?>
```

How do I pass the variable to another page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use a session to have variables float around in between files like that.

It's quite simple to setup. In the beginning of each PHP file, you add this code to begin a session:

```
session_start();
```

You can store variables inside of a session like this:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

And you can reference them across pages (make sure you run `session_start()` on all of the pages which will use sessions).

Answer (score 2):

**layouts.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$bgcolor = $_POST['bgcolor'];
$_SESSION['bgcolor'] = $bgcolor;
?>
```

**new.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['bgcolor'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise code (I accepted Blender's answer only because of the extra explanation).

Answer (score 0):

Give the form two `action=""` and see what happens. I just tried that on a script of mine and it worked fine.

A more proper way to solve this might exist, but that is an option.